# How to find the most recent date in a date column using VBA

Tags: vba, date, max

I have a column of dates which are linked to other data and I am happy with how they are sorted. So without sorting the data in the excel sheet I need to find the most recent and the oldest dates in that column.

I have had the following code so far which are not that helpful.

```
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("X")).Value

MsgBox Max_date
```

Thanks
H

Comment: So what is this code doing or not doing that is incorrect?

Comment: get rid of the `.value` at the end it is not part of the worksheet function

Comment: It gives me some numbers as output. But the numbers has no thing to do with the date that I am looking for.. Thanks Scott.

Comment: Are the number like `42056`?  If so that is the numerical form of the date.  Try `msgbox Cdate(max_date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove ".value" from your first line of code.

```
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("X"))
MsgBox Max_date
```

This returns the number that represents the date in Microsoft Excel date-time code.

To echo Scott Craner's comment, use the following to display the date formatted version of the number.

```
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("X"))
MsgBox cDate(Max_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple of ways to deal with this:

First you can deal with it at the time of the output by using CDate():

```
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("X"))
MsgBox CDate(Max_date)
```

Second You can declare the Max_date as a date and it will automatically make the switch:

```
Dim Max_date as Date
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("X"))
MsgBox Max_date
```

Personally I prefer the second as it will not allow non date values to be entered in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

MsgBox CDate(Max_date) will do it.

Dates are represented as numbers in Excel, with typical values around 40000.

CDate converts that number to a VBA date type.